# T-SQL basic questions: How to store result of a table-valued-function (for resusing data)?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table-valued-function working functionally well.  I wanted to reuse its result in multiple SELECT statements.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldinsert the results to a temp table or table variable. You could use the same table valued function in multiple statements but could run into issues if the data is changed from another source while the whole process is running, so I would say the temp table or table variable would be safer.